OneAPI icx: Support for GCC's quadmath and syntax of response files
Using:
Fedora Linux 40
Intel(R) oneAPI DPC++/C++ Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 2024.1.2 Build 20240508
I'm starting to work with OneAPI's icx compiler and from the start ran into 2 problems:

When I try to compile the following example code from the documentation of GCC's quadmath:

#include <quadmath.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  __float128 r;
  int prec = 20;
  int width = 46;
  char buf[128];

  r = 2.0q;
  r = sqrtq (r);
  int n = quadmath_snprintf (buf, sizeof buf, "%+-#*.20Qe", width, r);
  if ((size_t) n < sizeof buf)
    printf ("%s\n", buf);
    /* Prints: +1.41421356237309504880e+00 */
  quadmath_snprintf (buf, sizeof buf, "%Qa", r);
  if ((size_t) n < sizeof buf)
    printf ("%s\n", buf);
    /* Prints: 0x1.6a09e667f3bcc908b2fb1366ea96p+0 */
  n = quadmath_snprintf (NULL, 0, "%+-#46.*Qe", prec, r);
  if (n > -1)
    {
      char *str = malloc (n + 1);
      if (str)
        {
          quadmath_snprintf (str, n + 1, "%+-#46.*Qe", prec, r);
          printf ("%s\n", str);
          /* Prints: +1.41421356237309504880e+00 */
        }
      free (str);
    }
  return 0;
}

with
$>icx -c tes_quadmath_snprintf.c
I get the error message:
tes_quadmath_snprintf.c:2:10: fatal error: 'quadmath.h' file not found
When I was using icc, I did not need to explicitly include the path to the headers of  quadmath  in order to compile the code.
I thought that OneAPI was supposed to fully support GCC.  What is the best way to circumvent this error? Should I simply statically include (with '-I') the path to the headers?
2.  When I use response files to set the compiler options, according to the documentation here:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/dpcpp-cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2024-1/use-response-files.html
it seems that comments starting with '#' can not be included in the file, otherwise a lot of error messages pop up.  For instance, if I create the response1.txt file with
response file: response1.txt
compile with these options
-W0
end of response1 file
and try to compile with
$>icx @response1.txt ..
i get:
icx: error: no such file or directory: '#'
icx: error: no such file or directory: 'response'
icx: error: no such file or directory: 'file:'
icx: error: no such file or directory: '#'
icx: error: no such file or directory: 'compile'
icx: error: no such file or directory: 'with'
icx: error: no such file or directory: 'these'
icx: error: no such file or directory: 'options'
icx: error: no such file or directory: '#'
icx: error: no such file or directory: 'end'
icx: error: no such file or directory: 'of'
icx: error: no such file or directory: 'response1'
icx: error: no such file or directory: 'file'
Is this just a bug?
For question 1, including "-I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/14/include" of course solved the problem, but I want to avoid architecture-specific workarounds.
For question 2, leaving all comments out of the response file also solves the problem, but it goes against the example in the documentation.
